# Display a coupon code on single product pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, coupon

I want to display discount coupon on every product page on woocommerce for two reasons.

1. A lot of new customers overlooks discount coupons mentioned on home page and header of website despite my best intention.
2. With discount coupons I want to encourage more users to make prepaid payments and avoid Cash on Delivery.

Is this something possible to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Added the hook for cart page…

This can be done simply with the following, that will add a custom notice message with the coupon code in single product pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'custom_message_before_single_product', 5 ); // For single product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'custom_message_before_single_product'); // For cart page
function custom_message_before_single_product() {
    $coupon_code = 'special10';

    wc_print_notice( sprintf(
        __("You get %s when using credit card payment with the %s coupon code.", "woocommerce"),
        '<strong>' . __("a 10% discount", "woocommerce") . '</strong>',
        '<code>' . $coupon_code . '</code>'
    ), 'notice' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

You will get something like this in your single product pages:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but I was wondering if the same message can be displayed in cart page as well?